Is there a sequence of real functions which is a basis, with respect to infinite sum of linear combinations, of all real functions?

Does there exist a sequence of functions $f_n:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ such
that for every function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R},\ \exists\
 a_n\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(
 \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_nf_n(x) \right) = f(x)$ for each $x\in[0,1]?$
Such a sequence could be called a basis for the set of all functions
$f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}.$

Either such a sequence can be constructed and the axiom of choice is probably necessary, or we can prove by contradiction that such a sequence does not exist.
I think that for any countable subset $S$ of $[0,1]$ there are uncountably many ways to choose the $a_n$ to make this limit work for each member of $S.$ But I am not sure about uncountable subsets of $[0,1].$
Hamel basis is possibly relevant, though I have no experience with it.

You are taking limits, but you are considering the set of all possible functions $\mathbb R^{[0,1]}$ with no assumptions on regularity?

What do you mean by "(assumptions on ) regularity"?

Continuity, uniform continuity etc.

No, there are no assumptions on regularity. The question is written as intended.

Such a sequence does not exist: there are simply too many functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R$. If $(f_n)$ is a sequence of functions $f_n:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$, then there are at most $\mathfrak c^{\aleph_0}=\mathfrak c$ functions of the form $f=a_1f_1+a_2f_2+\cdots$, where $a_i\in\mathbb R$ for each $i$. But there are $\mathfrak c^\mathfrak c$ functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R$.
